# Calculated Column 21 business days from start date

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula

I have a field that is called Transmit Date, I need to generate a calculated column 21 business days from the date of this field. I have seen some other posts that fall within a week. I am curious how I set this up for 21 business days.

Answer (score 1):

**Please follow steps:**

1.Create a **Date and Time** column named "**Test_Data**"

[image]

2.Then, create a **Calculated** column called "**Transmit Date**" and copy the following **formula** to the Calculated column：`=IF(WEEKDAY(Test_Data)=1,Test_Data+21+2*4,IF(WEEKDAY(Test_Data)=6,Test_Data+21+2*5,IF(WEEKDAY(Test_Data)=7,Test_Data+21+2*4+1,Test_Data+21+2*4)))`

**Note:** The “**21**” represents the number of **working days**

[image]

3.The Final Display：

[image]

====================== **Updated Answer** =======================

By default, users need add square brackets ( **[ ]** ) for Column Name.

Eg. =[Column1]+[Column2]

More information, please refer to [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14)).

**Calculated column formula:**

```
=IF(WEEKDAY([Transmit Date])=1,[Transmit Date]+21+2*4,IF(WEEKDAY([Transmit Date])=6,[Transmit Date]+21+2*5,IF(WEEKDAY([Transmit Date])=7,[Transmit Date]+21+2*4+1,[Transmit Date]+21+2*4)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for looking at this. Still having trouble. In your example above your Test_Data is my Transmit Date and my Transmit Date is called Due Date. When putting this into the SharePoint list I get an error. I modified in one instance putting square brackets around Transmit Date bcs that seems to be how it usually wants the calculation of a field. However, I tried both ways: =IF(WEEKDAY[Transmit Date]=1,[Transmit Date]+21+2*4,IF(WEEKDAY[Transmit Date]=6,[Transmit Date]+21+2*5,IF(WEEKDAY[Transmit Date]=7,[Transmit Date]+21+2*4+1,[Transmit Date]+21+2*4)))  - Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, Elaine. Thanks for your reply. I have updated my answer, hope this can help you. Have a nice day!